# How to open toplevel windows sequentially?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, toplevel

What I'd like to achieve: main window with a button displaying a Toplevel window and displaying another Toplevel window after closing the previous one.
What my code does: main window with a button displaying a Toplevel window, but nothing happens after closing it. The second Toplevel window appears only when the main window is closed.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApp:
    def f1(self):

        def f1a():
            root_a = tk.Toplevel()
            root_a.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
            lab = tk.Label(root_a, text='toplevel1')
            lab.pack()
            exit_button = tk.Button(root_a, text='ok', command=root_a.destroy)
            exit_button.pack()
            root_a.mainloop()

        def f1b():
            root_b = tk.Toplevel()
            root_b.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
            lab2 = tk.Label(root_b, text="toplevel2")
            lab2.pack()
            exit_b = tk.Button(root_b, text='OK', command=root_b.destroy)
            exit_b.pack(side="left")
            root_b.mainloop()

        f1a()
        f1b()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.window_app = tk.Frame(parent, height=400, width=400)
        self.window_app.pack()
        self.process_button = tk.Button(parent, text="run function f1", command=self.f1)
        self.process_button.place(x=30, y=70, height=30, width=200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Calls to `.mainloop()` don't normally exit until *all* windows are closed.  Only the call at the very bottom should exist.

Comment: thanks! that's the hint I needed.

Comment: Instead of ```.mainloop()``` for Toplevel windows I used ```.wait_window()```